# Rails Background Process (Heroku Rails 3+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, heroku, rake

I'm am going to set up some functionality for my app that is Rails 3.2.3 and on Heroku. The idea is to have a task, or job (or whatever you want to call it) run every day, to make sure user information from the external API is up to date with the user information in my db. I'm curious what is the the best way to set this up? Should it be a cron job that runs a rake task?

Seems like there are quite a few ways to do this and I'm interested in the ways others are doing this. The only way I can think to do it is to run a rake task in a cron job, but would love to figure out what best practices are, or the most simple way to do it. Seems like there are a lot of ways to skin this cat... lots of different tools out there too.

If there was a pure rails way to do this, I think that would be better so I don't have to screw around with every system I place my app onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple sync job that runs once a day, I believe having a **cronjob** would be sufficient and likely more stable in the long run.

Honestly, solutions such as Resque and Sidekiq is a bit overkill in my opinion (for your needs). You're still required to use a scheduler to send messages to these systems.

Check out the gem '**whenever**' if you're looking at making the deployment and writing of crontabs easier: https://github.com/javan/whenever/

Railscasts regarding 'whenever': http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: oh yes, i have heard of whenever from railscasts and remember like the syntax... remember it being simple. i may finally try it out, thanks.

Comment: i also really like the idea of "cron jobs in ruby" because the functionality would be tied to my app, not a heroku add-on or some a cronjob that will have to be rerun on another system. just really like the idea of the functionality being contained in my app.

Comment: Exactly - and then if you transfer to another system (provided it is *nix), then you'll just run the whenever command and you're done. The config is stored in your app. Another alternative is using Capistrano to write to the crontab at deployment.

Comment: Note that if you have a site scaled to just one web process on Heroku, your instance may spin down during inactivity and no jobs will run (unless you use their scheduler, which is independent).

Comment: whenever is a good choice for scheduling recurring tasks. But I think you should use sidekiq also since your task is heavy. Use whenever to fire a sideqik task and that sideqik task will fire multiple tasks to fetch information for each user.

Comment: i decided to use whenever because i was familiar with it mainly, and it didn't require me to keep functionality outside of my app. i'll just find a clever way to keep heroku from spooling down since the problem is heroku itself, not my assp. @ismaelga i may try to use sideqik as well, if the implementation is simple, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options. They're better than options you mentioned in your question

1. [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/).
2. [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/).

Try the later one. It is faster, lightweight and based on multithreading so there isn't interference with system. You'll need to look into scheduler of both the gem for processing everyday.

Hope this helps!

Comment: With Sidekiq, what happens if the Sidekiq process quits unexpectedly? Does it have some type of watchdog process?

Comment: it retries!  I'm not sure about watchdog process. You can ask on their IRC channel

Comment: Apparently there is no documentation that mentions a watchdog. Not to mention you're still having to schedule messages to be sent. I don't agree that Resque and Sidekiq would be better than a simple crontab. Sometimes a simple method is better for daily task.

Comment: if your background-process is not heavy. Initiate it at start of program and at end of method give `sleep`. That would be the easiest (but not best) solution.

Comment: An easy solution, but still a bad way when it comes to reliability, IMHO. You're then relying on a constant process running, which could fail in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Heroku scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) add on to the handle scheduling itself.  You can have it run a rake task, resque, or whatever.

Comment: is Heroku schedule just a wrapper for cron? in the end i may not want to run my app on heroku, although i like heroku and will probably leave it there. but in the case that i move my app off heroku it seems as though i'd have to recreate this functionality, something i'd like to avoid.

Comment: I don't think cron works reliably on Heroku.  The filesystem isn't persistent or shared and you can have many instances, so you might end up with all of them running the same cron task and trying to feed your shared database.  Or if you have just one instance, it could spin down and forget utterly.  If the scheduling is separate from the task, though, it's pretty easy to replace Heroku scheduler with cron when running on another service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few to choose from :

1. [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/) (with [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler/). But you have to use redis with it)
2. [rufus-scheduler](http://rufus.rubyforge.org/rufus-scheduler/) ( if you want something simple, resque uses rufus-scheduler itself)
3. You may try [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with a few tricks like [this one](http://terrbear.org/2010/02/19/scheduling-jobs-with-delayedjob/). Not that great for scheduling but can use your application database.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @az7ar i will look into those. so far out of the suggestions 'whenever' is the one i've heard of... how would you compare 'whenever' to the tools you suggested?

Comment: I would say if you only want to do a task every day/hour/month then you dont need resque/delayed_job. You should either use rufus-scheduler or whenever.
I guess it comes down to personal preference between those two.